# Is there a way to programatically bind to InputBinding Command property?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I know it's a generic title, but my question is specific.  I think it will boil down to a question of practice.  So, I have the following code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MyViewModel viewModel = new MyViewModel();
    this.myGrid.DataContext = viewModel;
}

public class MyViewModel
{
    public ICommand SomeCommandProperty { get { return this.someCommandProperty; }}
}

public class ComponentCollection : Panel
{
    public ComponentCollection()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            this.Children.Add(new Component());
        }
    }
}

public class Component : UIElement
{
    public Component()
    {
        this.InputBindings.Add(new MouseBinding(SomeCommandProperty, new MouseGesture(MouseAction.LeftClick)));
    }
}
```

I could easily aggregate the ViewModel that owns SomeCommandProperty into the Component class, but I'm currently waiving that option assuming there is another way.

Component is a child of ComponentCollection which is child of a Grid which DataContext is MyViewModel. ComponentCollection as the name suggests contains a collection of Components.

```
<Grid Name="myGrid">
    <someNamespace:ComponentCollection x:Name="componentCollection"/>
</Grid>
```

It's the same scenario as the XAML below, but with TextBlock.  I guess I'm trying to replicate what's being done in the XAML below programatically.  Again, Component's top most ancestor's DataContext is set to ViewModel.

```
<Grid Name="myGrid">
    <TextBlock Text="SomeText">
        <TextBlock.InputBindings>
            <MouseBinding Command="{Binding SomeCommandProperty}" MouseAction="LeftClick" />
        </TextBlock.InputBindings>
    </TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

**Update 1**

Basically, I have a custom control which inherit from a Panel which children are a collection of Component.  It's not a hack, like I've mentioned, I could directly have access to ***SomeCommandProperty*** If I aggregate the ViewModel into Component.  Doing so, however, feels icky.  That is, having direct access to ViewModel from a Model.

I guess the question I'm asking is. Given the situation that Component's parent UIElement's DataContext is set to MyViewModel, is it possible to access **SomeCommandProperty** without ***Component*** owning a reference to the ***MyViewModel*** that owns **SomeCommandProperty**? Programatically, that is.

Using ItemsControl doesn't change the fact that I still need to bind SomeCommandProperty to each Items.

**Update 2**

See code above.

**Update 3**

Apparently, there isn't a mechanism I know of that will set the binding on the Command property of an InputBinding.

For example if my Component class were to Inherit from ButtonBase instead of UIElement, I would have the Command property to which I could easily set the binding **programatically** using FrameWorkElement's SetBinding.  Unfortunately, I can't do this with InputBinding's Command property.

```
public class Component : ButtonBase
{
    public Component()
    {
        System.Windows.Data.Binding binding = new System.Windows.Data.Binding
        {
            RelativeSource = new System.Windows.Data.RelativeSource(System.Windows.Data.RelativeSourceMode.FindAncestor, typeof(ComponentCollection), 1 ),
            Path = new PropertyPath("DataContext.SomeCommandProperty")
        };

        // I can do this.
        this.SetBinding(this.CommandProperty, binding);

        // But I want to do something like below.  Note: It's a pseudo code.
        MouseBinding mouseBinding = new MouseBinding();
        mouseBinding.SetBinding(mouseBinding.CommandProperty, binding);
        this.InputBindings.Add(mouseBinding);
    }
}
```

**Update 4**

BindingOperations.SetBinding can be used on Objects that don't have direct access to SetBinding.

**Solution**

```
        MouseBinding mouseBinding = new MouseBinding();
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(mouseBinding, MouseBinding.CommandProperty, binding);
        this.InputBindings.Add(mouseBinding);
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. Why don't you use an `ItemsControl` instead of resorting to all these horrible hacks?

Comment: I still don't understand the need for all this when there is already a built-in class in the framework that does it for you. use an ItemsControl.

Comment: I just tested using a `RelativeSource` binding on a MouseBinding.Command and it works. I fail to see what your problem is and why do you want to do this in code.

Comment: I know that RelativeSource binding works.  Anyway, I guess this turned out to be more of a newbie question. I just realized that @Leo Lorenzo already mentioned BindingOperations.

Comment: Glad I'm able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Use an [ItemsControl](http://drwpf.com/blog/itemscontrol-a-to-z/) for this. Don't try to hack something together yourself when there is a built-in class that already does this.

You can also access the ViewModel from a parent UI element in the Visual Tree by using a [RelativeSource](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/yougerthen/relativesources-in-wpf/) binding:

```
<ItemsControl>
   <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
          <TextBlock Text="SomeText">
              <TextBlock.InputBindings>
                  <!-- See how I'm using RelativeSource to get a hold of the DataContext of the parent ItemsControl -->
                  <MouseBinding Command="{Binding DataContext.SomeCommandProperty,
                                                  RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}" 
                                MouseAction="LeftClick" />
              </TextBlock.InputBindings>
          </TextBlock>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: I understand that base on my code example, it would seem that I'm trying to mimic what ItemsControl already does.  This is not the case, my project is much more complex.  The code is to show the hierarchy which resembles the situation I have.  My question is not what controls to use, but how to programatically bind.  Anyway, thanks for your post.  It will come in handy.  I've updated my question.

Comment: @M312v I fail to see how using a `RelativeSource` binding does not solve your problem. Can you please add more detail to this question?